# ogrinfo: error while loading shared libraries: libhdf5.so.6 on Centos 6

Tags: centos6

I installed Gdal on my centos 6 machine with command

```
  yum install gdal
```

But when I try to run

```
$ ogrinfo
```

I get following error

```
ogrinfo: error while loading shared libraries: libhdf5.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Here is a output of

```
$ldd /usr/bin/ogrinfo
```

http://pastebin.com/piRg3MNr

(Since output was big passted on pastebin)

Repo list

```
adobe-linux-i386    Adobe Systems Incorporated                               
base                CentOS-6 - Base                                          
elgis               EL GIS 6 - x86_64                                        
epel                Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64           
extras              CentOS-6 - Extras                                        
google-chrome       google-chrome                                            
remi                Les RPM de remi pour Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64         
remi-test           Les RPM de remi en test pour Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64 
rpmforge            RHEL 6 - RPMforge.net - dag                          
updates             CentOS-6 - Updates
```

Comment: Please give the `yum repolist` output.

Comment: I have updated with repolist, I did not understood why downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved I had to install it again. This time I build it from source code.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have `libhdf5` installed? It's part of the `hdf5` package.

Please run `which ogrinfo` and `ldd /path/to/orginfo` and post the output.

You need the `libhdf5.so.6` file. It's part of `hdf5`.

Can just you run `yum install hdf5` ?

Also you may have need to add your hdf5 library path to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: When I do locate I get

locate libhdf5
/usr/lib64/mpich2/lib/libhdf5.so.6
/usr/lib64/mpich2/lib/libhdf5.so.6.0.4
/usr/lib64/mpich2/lib/libhdf5_fortran.so.6
/usr/lib64/mpich2/lib/libhdf5_fortran.so.6.0.4
/usr/lib64/mpich2/lib/libhdf5_hl.so.6
/usr/lib64/mpich2/lib/libhdf5_hl.so.6.0.4
/usr/lib64/mpich2/lib/libhdf5hl_fortran.so.6
/usr/lib64/mpich2/lib/libhdf5hl_fortran.so.6.0.4

Comment: See edit above.

Comment: I have added my output in my question.

Comment: You just need to install hdf5. See above.

Comment: It still says libhdf5.so.6 => not found when I do ldd :(

Comment: Did you install hdf5?

Comment: Yes 

`Package hdf5-1.8.7-1.el6.rf.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the database file
`/etc/ld.so.cache`
wasn't updated automatically
try run 
`ldconfig`
as root and see if it works now